Using ROLLUP to add sums in the last row
I have the table below with the data. Here the code:
create table t(mon number, id number)

insert into t(mon, id)   
SELECT 4,   1006   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5,   10618  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   9999   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   9999   FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2,   1000   FROM DUAL UNION ALL

I wish to add sums in the last row.
I tried with this query:
select id, 
    coalesce(case when max(mon) = 1 then count(*) end, 0) Jan,
    coalesce(case when max(mon) = 2 then count(*) end, 0) Feb, 
    coalesce(case when max(mon) = 3 then count(*) end, 0) Mar,
    coalesce(case when max(mon) = 4 then count(*) end, 0) Apr,
    coalesce(case when max(mon) = 5 then count(*) end, 0) May,
    coalesce(case when max(mon) = 6 then count(*) end, 0) Jun, 
    count(*) from t group by rollup(id);

But I'm getting:
0   0   0   0   36  0   36

I wish to get:
0   2    0  1 33 0 36

The whole table with data is in DB Fiddle

Aggregate by id first and then do the ROLLUP to get the totals (if you try to do it all in one then the ROLLUP row will use the global maximum and not the maximum for each id).
SELECT id,
       SUM(CASE max_mon WHEN 1 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS Jan,
       SUM(CASE max_mon WHEN 2 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS Feb,
       SUM(CASE max_mon WHEN 3 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS Mar,
       SUM(CASE max_mon WHEN 4 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS Apr,
       SUM(CASE max_mon WHEN 5 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS May,
       SUM(CASE max_mon WHEN 6 THEN total ELSE 0 END) AS Jun,
       SUM(total) AS total
FROM   (
  SELECT id,
         MAX(mon) AS max_mon,
         COUNT(*) AS total
  FROM   t
  GROUP BY id
)
GROUP BY ROLLUP(id);

Which, for the sample data, outputs:



ID
JAN
FEB
MAR
APR
MAY
JUN
TOTAL




1006
0
0
0
1
0
0
1


10618
0
0
0
0
1
0
1


9999
0
2
0
0
0
0
2


1000
0
0
0
0
9
0
9


13071
0
0
0
0
8
0
8


1009
0
0
0
0
11
0
11


15344
0
0
0
0
1
0
1


14337
0
0
0
0
1
0
1


990
0
0
0
0
1
0
1


10907
0
0
0
0
1
0
1


null
0
2
0
1
33
0
36



fiddle

I wanna order by total desc but wish to have the sums in the las row. How can i do that?
And would it be possible to do the whole select in one query while not using  MAX(mon) and just mon instead?

@hajduk Add ORDER BY GROUPING_ID(id), total, id fiddle. It is all in one query; the inner SELECT creates an inline view which is used by the outer SELECT so it only needs to query the table once.

I see. Thank you. But I mean would it be possible to do it without the inner query as well?
